# Asus motherboard: one long beep, 3 short beeps, one short beep

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard

When my computer starts, monitor shows no signal, you can hear the computer trying to do something (almost sounds like starting a car with multiple tries). Then I hear one long beep, three short beep, a brief pause, and then another short beep.

My Asus motherboard is a P5N-E SLI.

I thought it was the RAM. So I removed all 3 of the installed DIMS. And replaced it with a new one. When I turned it on, still same issue: one long beep, 3 short beeps, brief pause, and another beep.

I looked at ASUS beep codes:

http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm

It suggests this is a sign of "No video card or bad video RAM". I took out the video card and reinserted it firmly. This got the same issue.

Then I removed the only DIM I still had in there, and when I turned on the computer, I got the repeated beeps, which is a memory error, I suppose, since I had no RAM in computer.

So based on what I have done so far, I believe that the issue is not RAM. I believe the issue is not CPU or motherboard either, otherwise I would have gotten different kind of beeps or no beeps at all.

Should I buy a new video card? (the one I bought in 2007 was a cheap sparkle geoforce for 30 dollars). Or is there another issue at play that I should consider?

Comment: I think well done on your efforts, but I would suggest borrowing it buying a very cheap one just to test. I'm also not sure what the question is as you already seem to know the answer.  I guess if new card fails then it is an issue but I agree with your idea

Comment: Did you by any chance do any overclocking? The "starting a car with multiple tries" sounds like what my asus mobo does when I over-overclock.

Comment: If your mobo had built-in video I'd have asked you to try if it works. But in this case you could only try borrowing/buying a video card and trying it. If that works then the original video card is faulty. Otherwise something else is faulty - probably your mobo itself since your CPU goes through more stringent testing by manufacturer.

Comment: I changed the graphics card and the system made POST and booted ubuntu. So it appears the graphics card was the issue.

Comment: @mniip today I noticed that the sound of a starting ignition is actually one of the dvd burners. It makes this weird noise 6 times before POST. And when it makes the noise, the LED on the dvd burner flashes green. I have another dvd burner also on system, so I'm probably just going to remove the one making the noise.

Answer (score 0):

My Asus Prime A320M-K board does this when No monitor is attached and ON.

So if I turn on HDMI monitor then turn pc on it stops beeping
1 Long, 3 short Beeps.

If HDMI cable is detached or Monitor is off the beeps return.